# htaccess rewrite a multi-query string into a path

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, query-string

How would i go about changing the query string

```
file.php?id=number&string=some-words
```

into this

```
file/number/some-words/
```

I know this has been asked a million times before, but I've looked at a number of solutions on here and they were all single query based (as in just ?something and not ?something&something-else).

Also once rewritten, does the php still read the original page query-string when using $_GET or $_REQUEST etc... even though it now appears as a path?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`RewriteRule` takes a regular expression which can be as complicated as you want it followed by the real URL that will load your file. You put parenthesis around the parts you want to capture in the regex and can reference those with `$1` for first group, `$2` for second group and so on in the URL part. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\d+)/(.*)$ index.php?file=$1&id=$2&words=$3
```

This would match 3 groups:

1. letters/numbers up to the first slash
2. some numbers up to the second slash
3. anything after that including additional slashes

And those can be referenced by `$1`, `$2`, `$3` as seen in the second part with index.php.

The only issue with this though is that if you are missing any one part, the pattern in the rule won't match. So you either need to have a separate rule for each variant:

```
#matches all 3 parts
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\d+)/(.*)$ index.php?file=$1&id=$2&words=$3
#matches the first 2 parts
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\d+)$ index.php?file=$1&id=$2
#matches just the first part
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ index.php?file=$1
#matches everything else
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php
```

Or you can do what is usually called `bootstrapping` which is where you use a single `RewriteRule` to redirect everything to a single php file like so:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php
```

And then you can just use php to determine what the different parts are. Inside php there is a built in server variable `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` that will give you the `URI` part of the url which is everything after the domain and first slash including any query string parameters. This is based on the URL that the user requested and not the one rewritten by apache. You can `explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])` to get the individual parts and do whatever you want with them.

Comment: I dont understand how the above will change the page address to a path instead of a query string, basically a permalink. When i use RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(\d+)/(.*)$ file.php?id=$1&string=$2 and then navigate to file/1/a-string/ it just goes to the 404 page.

Comment: I fixed it by changing the rule to RewriteRule ^file/(\d+)/(.*)$ file.php?id=$1&string=$2

Comment: Your pattern is incorrect. You have `^(\d+)/(.*)$` which means "Start of URI" followed by "one or more numbers" followed by a slash and then "anything" up to the end of the string (`$`). You are loading the URI with `file` in the front. You could do `^file/(\d+)/(.*)$` or you can make the `file` part generic and another matching group and do `^(\w+)/(\d+)/(.*)$` which will match any numbers/letters in the first part.

Answer (score 0):

You can place your code in Apache .htaccess files. This could look something like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^users/(\d+)*$ ./profile.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^threads/(\d+)*$ ./thread.php?id=$1

RewriteRule ^search/(.*)$ ./search.php?query=$1
```

Or you can use only htaccess and php:

htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^.*$ ./index.php
```

PHP

```
    <?php
  #remove the directory path we don't want
  $request  = str_replace("/envato/pretty/php/", "", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

  #split the path by '/'
  $params     = split("/", $request);
?>
```

And it will still read the original page query-string.